# How to call a method with question mark via send in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have methods generated for a list of symbols. One of the methods includes a question mark in its definition. I want to invoke such a method with a variable holding that symbol.

Suppose we generate a method for :check_element symbol and the corresponding method signature would look like.

```
class A
    def check_element?

    end
end
```

Now I have a variable `flag = :check_element` and I'm unable to call the method like `A.send(flag)`

but `A.send((flag.to_s + '?').to_sym)` works.

I'm thinking if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I guess there's always `"#{flag}?"` or `:"#{flag}?"` (if you really want a symbol even though `send` is quite happy with a string).

Comment: @thebenman : Can't you simply set `flag = :check_element?` ?

Comment: _"Suppose we generate a method for :check_element symbol and the corresponding method signature would look like"_ – why would the generated method name for `:check_element` end with a `?`. Where does the question mark come from?

Comment: BTW, `check_element?` is an _instance_ method – you can't invoke it via `A.send(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to translate the method name argument to a symbol because [send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-send) accepts a string too. That allows simplifying your example to

```
A.send(flag.to_s + '?')
```

Which can be simplified using string interpolation to

```
A.send("#{flag}?")
```

Comment: Please always suggest using `public_send` instead of `send` whenever possible for the semantical clarity.